# Iphone dev: Basic static page navigation?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

This is an incredibly basic question, but I'm not sure what's the best method of doing this professionally.

Suppose I want to make an app where the user just taps through multiple pages (a page might just be a screen with a background image and a few buttons). Now and then they might tap back to access a previous page.

I've come from cocos2d, so what's actually the best way to do this with Cocoa Touch? Do I have a seperate view for each page and just keep adding/removing them to the main view controller? Would I load everything at the start or drop a page from memory when the user clicks away?

Please give me a general approach as to how you would do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that is to use a `UINavigationController`. You can do something like this :

AppDelegate.h

```
UINavigationController *navigationController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize navigationController;
// In ApplicationDidFinishLaunching
UIViewController *yourMainViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourMainViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

in YourMainViewController.m

```
// When you click on a button
[[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourNewViewController animated:YES];
```